# Consuming Multiple .NET Web Services from Javascript in Parallel

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I have two ASMX web services consumed from javascript. The first service performs a long operation and updates a database table on its progress. The second service polls that same database table in order to report the progress to the end user via a progress bar.

My problem is that the long process seems to be blocking the polling service. When I log the activity of the javascript, it seems to be requesting the long service correctly, and then starts to request the polling service once a second asynchronously (note: the long process is asynch as well). Both request types either use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` which shouldn't halt the browser. Yet when I look at the activity of the javascript, none of the responses from the polling requests return until the long process completes. So it seems the long process is blocking the polling requests until it's done.

Here's the nitty gritty:

JavaScript:

```
var percentComplete = 0;
setTimeout(function ()
{
    MyWebService.CreateBulkOrder(serverVariable, function (result, eventArgs)
    {
        percentComplete = 100;
        completeOperation(result);
    });
}, 0);
var intID = setInterval(function ()
{
    if (percentComplete < 100)
    {
      MyWebService.GetStatus(serverVariable, callback);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(intID);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Service Code (VB.NET - Note: code is changed to make it generic)

```
   <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://mydns.com/webservices")>
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<ToolboxItem(False)>

Public Class MyWebServices
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Function GetStatus(serverVariable As Integer) As Object
    Dim currentPage As Integer = 0
    Dim totalPages As Integer = Math.Ceiling(CType(If(Session("Number of Records"), Double) / CType(ConstantsCommon.TOTAL_PER_PAGE, Double))
    Using clientDB As ClientDataContext = FunctionsOrderMgmt.ClientConnectionReadOnly
        Dim repeatPageQuery = From repeatPage In clientDB.RepeatPages
                              Where repeatPage.KEY = serverVariable
                              Select repeatPage
        Dim repeatPageData = repeatPageQuery.SingleOrDefault()
        If repeatPageData Is Nothing Then
            currentPage = 0
        Else
            currentPage = If(repeatPageData.REPEAT_PAGE, 0)
        End If
        Return New With {.TotalPages = totalPages, .CurrentPage = currentPage}
    End Using
End Function

<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Function CreateBulkOrder(serverVariable As Integer) As Boolean
    If Not TestsPass Then
        Return False
    End If
    Try
        'Do stuff that takes a long time
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up trying a different algorithm to avoid this issue, but I'm still pretty curious. I'm starting to think it has something to do with javascript not truly being multithreaded even though setInterval and setTimeout work for most cases. Any javascript experts know if that's accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'OneWay = true' to the CreateBulkOrder Webmethod otherwise it will be waiting for a response.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapdocumentmethodattribute.oneway(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris! It still seems to be blocking though. I know the OneWay is being processed because it threw an error on it having a return value. When I made it a Sub (a void function in C#) everything executes with no errors, except the long process is blocking the execution of the polling process until it completes.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to the process to determine if/when the status method is being called. It might help to track down the delay as it could be something you are not expecting.

Comment: Yeah, I placed breakpoints in both services and both are working perfectly except for the blocking. I also tried moving one of the services to a different ASMX page just in case there was some sort of lock on the ASMX file, but I had no luck.